# why MessageDlg show only "OK" button under windows?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

With `delphi 10.2.2 firemonkey`, under `windows`, when i do :

```
MessageDlg('Are you sure you want to undo the last operation ?', // const AMessage: string;
             TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation, // const ADialogType: TMsgDlgType;
             [TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes, TMsgDlgBtn.mbCancel], // const AButtons: TMsgDlgButtons;
             0, // const AHelpContext: THelpContext;
             TMsgDlgBtn.mbCancel, // const ADefaultButton: TMsgDlgBtn;
             procedure(const AResult: TModalResult)
             begin
               if AResult = mrYes then begin
               end;
             end); // const ACloseDialogProc: TInputCloseDialogProc);
```

then only a "**OK**" button is show in the popup dialog (no "**cancel**" nor "**yes**"). Is it normal or I miss something ?

Comment: You use _"incompatible"_ button set. For _"Yes"_ there is _"No"_, not _"Cancel"_ (see `TFMXDialogService.MessageDialog` method how checks the button combinations).

Comment: thanks @Victoria this is the answer not a comment ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens because Delphi checks valid button combinations and for the combination of **Yes** and **Cancel** there's no corresponding [**dialog box type**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) on Windows platform. That you get just dialog with the **OK** button is because the structure passed to the Windows API function is zeroed at the beginning and the value of the **uType** parameter **MB_OK** is just 0.

The Windows implementation of this is inside the **TFMXDialogService.MessageDialog** method, within the **FMX.Dialogs.Win** module.